# creating a "like" filter on a sharepoint list view

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, filter

I got a webpart displaying the content of a view containing the contents of a document library.
I can add another webpart ("Text filter") and connect this with the webpart displaying the data.
If the view contains three elements "car, caroussel and camageddon) the filter will only display the first row, when I enter "car" as a search value, but I want all three to be displayed.

I need something like a "where like %searchterm%" 
Is there another webpart for that or a property I did miss ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can use this in a document library (i think you can though) check out this link : http://sharethelearning.blogspot.com/2007/03/filtering-list-by-partial-match.html

Basically you need to create a data view web part and the other would be a filter that would lookup the values of the certain column you would want to.